# SQL - Change Name Of All Tables To All Camel Case Starting With Caps

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to rename my tables in my DB to use camel case starting with a caps. So for example I need `address` to be `Address` and `userinformation` to `UserInformation`.

When I use the command

```
RENAME TABLE `address` TO `Address`
```

It spits back an error saying `Table 'Address' already exists`

Any way around this?

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is holy, tag your DBMS when asking a question like this...

Comment: How are you determining words?  user_information would be easy, while userinformation not so much.  Could be UserInformation or even UserInFormation

Comment: Will it let you rename it to `Address_tempname` then after that rename it to `Address`?

Comment: I went ahead and took that route, good idea @HartCO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue results from case-insensitivity, those names are identical as far as the db is concerned. If you just want to standardize the names you can do so with an intermediate name:

```
RENAME TABLE `address` TO `Address_tempName`;
RENAME TABLE `Address_tempName` TO `Address`;
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySql guide, you must check the system variable named `lower_case_table_names` before run `RENAME TABLE`

This variable is stored in `my.ini` file.

If this variable doesn't exist in `my.ini` file, you can add it

Ther default value is 0 and the possible value are 0, 1, 2

You can check its effect [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)

And if you see [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) guide advices you how apply a `RENAME TABLE` from T1 table into t1 table.